# Code too large on Ant in Linux but compiles on Eclipse in Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a java file containing an Enum which is very large. the code compiles on Eclipse with JDK 1.8 but fails to do so on Linux when I do an ant build with the same JDK. It is really weird. But, more importantly, is there a fix for compiling codes that are really huge? My friends told me that from Java 1.7, the compilers do not throw that error. Is it true? Can anybody let me know? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eclipse normally uses its own compiler (called 'ecj') rather than the 'javac' compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there absolutely no fix to compile this code without splitting it or modifying the code, etc. ?? Or, is there a way to tell Ant to ignore this error?

Comment: What error do you get when compiling from command line with Ant ? Also, can you run the ant target from in eclipse ? If so, what happens then.
Lastly, if your Enum is so big the I seriously suggest some form of refactoring is required.

Comment: `/my/path/to/long/code/containing/enum/code.java:18: error: code too large` . Currently, I am using JDK 1,8.0_25. the Ant versions on Linux and Windows are same. And the JDK's are same on both I guess. How do i check which JDK eclipse uses to compile using ant?

Comment: I can confirm that sometimes antlr (v3.2) throwing code too large error in java 8, while not throwing such error in Java 7 at the same input.

Answer (score 0):

> A single method in a Java class may be at most 64KB of bytecode.

This is probably a sign that you should refactor your code ...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this piece of information. But then 1. how does eclipse compile it?
2. I am on the look out for methods to solve this issue WITHOUT refactoring my code.

Comment: Eclipse is probably more permissive than the standard compiler. And i don't think there is a way to force the standard jdk to override this limitation, maybe you can use eclipse compiler in ant rather than the standard jdk